# How to get a sub folder git path?

Tags: git

I download a project source code using `git clone`.

The project I downloaded contains many subfolder.

I want to know the git path of a given sub folder in order to download only this subfolder using `git clone`

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Unlike with SVN, for example, a Git repository is a discrete entity. You can only clone a repository as a whole, not single files or folders of it.